# Prevent Advertised shortcut from coming to the Start menu

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, installshield, wix3.5

I have an installer that will install the following shortcuts. The shortcuts are supposed to be installed in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyAPPFolder . But the issue is that a temporary shortcut will also create in the Start Menu and if I click on that the shortcut will disappear. I don't want the shortcut to be appear in the Start menu and want it to appear only in  MyAPPFolder and should uninstall everything while uninstalling the installer. Also if i remove the Advertise=yes from my code this issue won't come but this time the shortcuts won't get uninstalled correctly.

```
ProgramMenu
  MyAPPFolder
    Shortcut1Advertise
    Shortcut2Advertise
    Shortcut3Advertise
    Shortcut3Advertise
enter
```

The  code for installling the shortcut is given below.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="Shortcuts_Component_Group1" Directory="test">
  <Component Id="cmpShortcuts1" Guid="{0CD394A2-1D7B-44A0-A85A-EC17E2816BDD}">
    <File Id="File1" Name="File.test" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.Test_File_Path)File.test" >
      <Shortcut Id="Shortcut1Advertiseid" Directory="MyAPPFolder" Name="Shortcut1Advertise" ShortName="Test1" Description="Shortcut1Advertise" Arguments="/x test1" Icon="test.ico"  WorkingDirectory="test" Advertise="yes"/>
       <Shortcut Id="Shortcut2Advertiseid" Directory="MyAPPFolder" Name="Shortcut2Advertise" ShortName="Test2" Description="Shortcut2Advertise" Arguments="/x test2" Icon="test.ico"  WorkingDirectory="test" Advertise="yes"/>
    </File>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="cmpShortcuts2" Guid="F9032ED8-2F25-4852-B437-38AE61EE7F57">
  <File Id="File2" Name="File2.test" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.test_File_Path)\File2.test">
     <Shortcut Id="Shortcut3Advertiseid" Directory="MyAPPFolder" Name="Shortcut3Advertise" ShortName="Test1" Description="Shortcut3Advertise" Arguments="/x test3" Icon="test.ico"  WorkingDirectory="test" Advertise="yes"/>
      <Shortcut Id="Shortcut1Advertiseid" Directory="MyAPPFolder" Name="Shortcut4Advertise" ShortName="Test1" Description="Shortcut4Advertise" Arguments="/x test4" Icon="test.ico"  WorkingDirectory="test" Advertise="yes"/>
    </File>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: I had to go back and refresh my memory about Advertised shortcuts. But advertised shortcuts should go exactly where you tell it to go. My guess at this point is that the path to 'MyAPPFolder' doesn't resolve correctly when the feature is flagged for advertised. Check the msi log. Does the path for the shortcut resolve correctly? If not then check to see what component sets this value.

Comment: Shortcut get created in the  MyAPPFolder.But the issue is that a temporary shortcut will also create in the Start Menu and if I click on that the shortcut will disappear. I don't want the shortcut to be appear in the Start menu and want it to appear only in  MyAPPFolder and should uninstall everything while uninstalling the installer